# What is the meaning of "esta ciudad de mi alma"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

> Una muchedumbre de mujeres libres enriquecieron hasta el delirio las
>   viejas cantinas de la calle Ancha, que fuera después el camellón
>   Abello y ahora es el paseo Colón, **en esta ciudad de mi alma** tan
>   apreciada de propios y ajenos por la buena índole de su gente y la
>   pureza de su luz. (Garcia Marquez, Memorias de mis putas tristes)
>
> Translation (Grossman):
>   A crowd of free women
>   enriched to the point of delirium the old taverns along Calle Anche, which later was known as Camellَn Abello,
>   and now is called Paseo Colَn, **in this city of my soul** loved so much by both natives and outsiders for the good
>   character of its people and the purity of its light.

I do not seem to be able to understand what the author means by "esta ciudad de mi alma" or "this city of my soul".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Esta ciudad de mi alma"`, in Spanish language, means that is like the first love you had when you were young. **You love the city so so so much and you can't live without it**.

The traduction "this city of my soul" doesn't correspond with the spanish expression.

Did you understand me?

Comment: Thank you, I guess I got you. So, do you think the translation "city of my soul" is not a good equivalent?

Comment: I think so. I think the best equivalent is... "My beloved city", maybe?

Comment: Carlos: welcome to [spanish.se]! Thanks for all your posts today. Note I removed the greetings, since we want to keep the post as succint as possible and to go to the point. You can also take a look at the [tour] to learn more about the site. Thanks and see you around.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada, as I understand from your answer, "X de mi alma" somehow means one's first love, right?

Comment: @fedorqui all right, I didn't know that wasn't allowed. So sorry.

Comment: @JasonStack correct. A feeling equivalent to that.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada do not worry at all. It is not that is not allowed, it is just that it is discouraged and we want things to look as good as possible :) Thanks for your understanding!